# I get an error : class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get an error when checking the bounds for null:

```
   boundsBuilder.include(new LatLng(loc.getLocation().getLat(), loc.getLocation().getLng()));
   bounds = boundsBuilder.build();
                    if (bounds != null) {
                        LatLng northEast = bounds.northeast;
                        LatLng southWest = bounds.southwest;
                        double movingDistance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(northEast, southWest);
                        Log.i("TRIP", "checkoutTime movingDIstance is:" + movingDistance);
                        if (movingDistance >= kPSGeofencingShortDistance) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (activeTrip.getDeparture_time() < time + 1)
                            time = loc.getTimestamp() / 1000 + 1;
                        Log.i("TRIP", "checkoutTime time is:" + time);
                    }
```

Error is :

```
error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found
```

This are my dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:transition:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2+'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1+'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0+'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar')
implementation 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.1'
implementation 'io.smooch:core:latest.release'
implementation 'io.smooch:ui:latest.release'
implementation "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:recyclerviewheader2:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
implementation 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
implementation 'com.github.kaknazaveshtakipishi:PermissionEverywhere:1.0.2'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation(
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
)
implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.brandongogetap:stickyheaders:0.5.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And am using this gradle version:

```
   compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Try to update `google-services plugin:`

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'`

Comment: Nope, neither with 4.0.1 or 3.3.1

Comment: @NileshRathod do you know where I can check the latest version of play-services-maps?

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Use Latest version of `play-services`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

```
API                                        Description in build.gradle


Google+                                     com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1
Google Account Login                        com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
Google Actions, Base Client Library         com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1
Google Sign In                              com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1
Google Analytics                            com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2
Google Awareness                            com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:15.0.1
Google Cast                                 com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:15.0.1
Google Cloud Messaging                      com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1
Google Drive                                com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1
Google Fit                                  com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:15.0.1
Google Location and Activity Recognition    com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
Google Maps                                 com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
Google Mobile Ads                           com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
Google Places                               com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1
Mobile Vision                               com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2
Google Nearby                               com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:15.0.1
Google Panorama Viewer                      com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:15.0.1
Google Play Game services                   com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1
SafetyNet                                   com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1
Android Pay                                 com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1
Wear OS by Google                           com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1
```

Comment: I did this, and because analytics is 15.0.2 and others are 15.0.1 it says that I need to align them, but there is no 15.0.1 for analytics. So still not building

Comment: @rosualin happy to hear that