# error: cannot access zzbgl class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, build.gradle

I am running my android application am getting error

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'      
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
```

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get an error : class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872053/i-get-an-error-class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzbgl-not-found)

Comment: i have updated all dependencies but it is not working and gives error i have checked your link also

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
Please match version in both and use latest version then this will resolve error....Happy coding

Answer (score 5):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

use this dependency to solve zzbgl class problem

Comment: it's helped me.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
Please match version in both and use latest version then this will resolve error....Happy coding