# Android Studio com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an app in production that uses the Places SDK, I received an email from Google saying that the Places SDK for Google Maps Platform were deprecated, so I followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_compatibility_library) to Install the compatibility library.

the build.gradle looks like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0'
```

When I try to build the app I get the following error:

> error: cannot access zzbgl class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Comment: Your dependencies look archaic, make sure you've migrated to AndroidX first.

Comment: `places-compat` is also extremely useless without `places`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get an error : class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872053/i-get-an-error-class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzbgl-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can find your answer in the link below(it is a possible duplicate of ):

[I get an error : class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872053/i-get-an-error-class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzbgl-not-found/50872467)